# "isKindOfClass" Always Testing True in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented my own custom subclasses for CCSprite within my Cocos2d application however when iterating through my children my isKindOfClass is returning true for my CCLabelTTf which isn't a subclass of my GameCharacter.

```
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects = [self children];
      for (id tempObj in listOfGameObjects) {
        if ([tempObj isKindOfClass:[GameCharacter class]]) {
          GameCharacter *gameChar = (GameCharacter*)tempObj;
          [gameChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:delta andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];
        }  
      }
```

Comment: Inside the if condition, try printing the `tempObj` using an NSLog and make sure the class is `CCLabelTTf`. Is there any chance that it gets converted to that class?

Comment: Alternatively, you can check with `isMemberOfClass` as well. But that wont check for the inheritance.

Comment: The log doesn't say it is a CCLabelTTf, but how is that happening?

Comment: Print the `listOfGameObjects` array then and check the objects inside that.

Comment: yeah I wouldn't be surprised if that were yet another quirk by CCArray ….

Comment: to log the class name of the tempObj: 

    NSLog(@"obj class: %@", NSStringFromClass([tempObj class]));

Comment: This doesn't answer your question per se, but instead of checking the class of the object, you could evaluate whether the tempObj responds to the selector `updateStateWithDeltaTime:andListOfGameObjects:` and then perform the selector.

Comment: @Sylvan I had tried that and it says that it responds to the selector and when it calls, it crashes.

Comment: I didn't get to solve this problem, but it disappeared after I added all of the GameCharacters to my SpriteBatchNode.